# Discord.JS - Embed is not appearing

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

The help command will not show when I do "?help", I get no errors either and just cannot figure out why it's not appearing, please help.

```
let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
  
    .setTitle("Haunt Bot Commands")
  
    .setDescription('Utility: ?invite | ?support | ?prefix | ?avatar | ?info | ?whois',
                    'Query: ?calculate | ?anime',
                    'Moderation: ?kick | ?ban | ?mute | ?warn | ?purge | ?warnings',
                    'Economy: ?bal | ?daily | ?roll | ?bet | ?give',
                    'Music: ?play | ?np | ?lyrics | ?pause | ?search | ?queue | ?skip | ?vol',
                    'Fun: ?kiss | ?hug | ?pat | ?slap | ?wink | ?cuddle',
                    'NSFW: ?neko | ?foxgirl')
  
    .setThumbnail(bot.user.avatarURL({dynamic:true, size: 1024}))
    .setFooter("Thank you so much for choosing Haunt, it means the world to me! <3")
    .setColor("#78d7fa")
    
    return message.noMentionReply(embed);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is "noMentionReply"? Where did you get that from? I'm pretty sure the correct function is

```
message.channel.send(message);
```

```
 let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("Haunt Bot Commands")
  .setDescription('Utility: ?invite | ?support | ?prefix | ?avatar | ?info | ?whois',
                'Query: ?calculate | ?anime',
                'Moderation: ?kick | ?ban | ?mute | ?warn | ?purge | ?warnings',
                'Economy: ?bal | ?daily | ?roll | ?bet | ?give',
                'Music: ?play | ?np | ?lyrics | ?pause | ?search | ?queue | ?skip | ?vol',
                'Fun: ?kiss | ?hug | ?pat | ?slap | ?wink | ?cuddle',
                'NSFW: ?neko | ?foxgirl')
  .setThumbnail(bot.user.avatarURL({dynamic:true, size: 1024}))
  .setFooter("Thank you so much for choosing Haunt, it means the world to me! <3")
  .setColor("#78d7fa")

 message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a "noMentionReply" function on the message object unless you defined it somewhere. If you meant to use a function, just do "noMentionReply(embed)"